# Font Rendering Issue

Tags: linux, fonts, rendering, sublimetext3, gnome-terminal

I have a problem with my font rendering under Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca with Kernel 3.17.1. 
The spacing for monospace fonts is really wrong, some letters are bold and misplaced. At some places the font appears italic and I don't know why. It just looks terrible.

Gnome Terminal:

[image: Gnome Terminal]

Sublime Text:

[image: Sublime]

The font settings are set to default:

- Default Font: Noto Sans 9
- Desktop Font: Noto Sans 10
- Document Font: Noto Sans 10
- Monospace Font: Monospace 10
- Window Title Font: Noto Sans Bold 10,
- Text Scaling Factor: 1.0
- Antialiasing: Rgba
- Hinting: Slight

Antialiasing and Hinting are not the problem! Also, I did not touch the fonts themselves (I also ran `diff`).

The problem does appear when I log in with different users, and in *cinnamon* as well as in *i3*.
I am not using a custom `~/.config/fontconfig` file and did not change `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`.

Even if I change the font in Sublime to "Times", only numbers seem to be affected.

The problem affects the following applications:

- Gnome Terminal (using the system's font)
- Terminator
- Sublime Text

while it does not affect:

- Firefox (and other browsers)
- Android Studio
- GTK Applications (like Gnome Settings, Abiword...)

Comment: Neither of your screenshots shows a monospaced font

Comment: this sounds more like a general OS problem than a programming problem. As a question that isn't related to any code you wrote or use being responsible for this issue, please ask this over on http://www.superuser.com instead.

Comment: @idleberg I know, but it is set to Monospace, that's the problem.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I agree with you. I asked this question on superuser before, but since I did not find anything helpful myself and nobody answered there, I thought I could give it a try here where more people get to see it. But it felt wrong to post it...